# How is the Checksum from Hex file calculated?

Tags: binary, hex

as the title says I'm curious to know how the checksum value is calculated, from what I've read it calculated using 2s complement. Below is a 2 lines from the hex file which was loaded onto my Microcontroller, I've added spaces to make it easier to read, S315 appears on every line, the address on line 1 is 080C0000 followed by 16 hex values which represent the bytes, the values AA on line 1 and AB on line 2 are I assume the checksum values.

For line 1 I've tried adding the following `15+08+0C+00+00+4D+53+53+70+6F+74+31+00+66+10+AE+19+7E+63+1F+78` which gives me `555` Hex or `‭010101010101‬` in binary. I've entered the binary value into an online 2s complement calculator but it always says "invalid binary"??

S3 15 080C0000 4D 53 53 70 6F 74 31 00 66 10 AE 19 7E 63 1F 78 **AA**

S3 15 080C0010 00 00 00 00 45 85 63 EB FF FF FF FF 04 00 03 00 **AB**

Comment: What kind of file? From what you've read where? Checksum or CRC? NB the term is twos *complement*, not 'compliment'.

Comment: Note 0x55 + 0xaa adds up to 0xff. Just saying ...

Comment: @EJP - It is a .hex file

Comment: And what is a .hex file? Where is it specified?

Comment: It is a file which contains program instructions for my Microcontroller

Comment: It is not specific for a single microcontroller. He's talking about the Intel HEX format, which is a standard used by many vendors for years (decades probably).

Comment: Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You add the byte values, like you've done. From that sum you take only the least significant byte.

Then for Motorola HEX (SREC):
Then you take the one's complement of that byte by inverting its bits (i.e. 1s turns to 0s and vice versa).

Then for Intel HEX:
Then you take the two's complement of that byte by inverting its bits (i.e. 1s turns to 0s and vice versa) and then you add 1.

Going by your example you have the sum 0x555. Then take the least significant byte, which is 0x55.

For Motorola HEX (SREC): Calculate the one's complement of that. You get 0xAA as the checksum.

For Intel HEX: Calculate the two's complement of that. You get 0xAB as the checksum.

Comment: Okay, 0x55 is 0xAA inverted? I didn't need to subtract 1 from it

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit unclear - if you take the twos-complement of 0x55, you get 0xAB. Then you need to subtract 1 to get 0xAA.

Comment: 0x55 is 01010101, and the inverted bits will be 10101010 or 0xAA??

Comment: Keep it simple. The twos complement of X is -X.

Comment: @DavidMcQillan Yes, you're correct. But if you just invert the bits, you get the one's complement. To get the two's complement, you need to also add one.

Comment: @DavidMcQillan Ah, I figured out what's the matter. You're actually not using Intel HEX-format, instead you're using software that uses the Motorola HEX-format. In that format the checksum is the one's complement. So you just need to invert the bits, and do no more.

Comment: Okay thanks for you help, I'll need read up more on how this works

Comment: @DavidMcQillan: The general idea is that when parsing the HEX-file you can just sum the data bytes _and_ the checksum, and every line should give you 0. The difference is just whether negative numbers are represented by one's complement or two's complement.